# Increments of discrete i.i.d. random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We are given a sequence of discrete i.i.d. random variables $X_0, X_1, \ldots$. Let $Y_i = X_{i+1} - X_i$. Are the $Y_i$ independent? I was trying to show

\begin{equation}
P(Y_{1} = k_1, \ldots, Y_{n} = k_n) \,=\, P(Y_{1} = k_1) \cdot \ldots \cdot P(Y_{n} = k_n)
\end{equation}

but failed to do it even for $Y_0$ and $Y_1$. What happens if $X_i$ are uncorrelated instead of independent?

Comment: Try to compute $\mathbb{E} Y_1 Y_2$ vs $\mathbb{E} Y_1 \mathbb{E} Y_2$.

Comment: I see. We have $\mathbb E[Y_1 Y_2] = \text{Var}(X_i)$ and $\mathbb E[Y_1]\mathbb E[Y_2] = 0$. Thus, $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are not independent! I read in a book that they are supposed to be and that's why I didn't try the expectation stuff as it does not imply independence. If you put it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: actually $\mathbb E[Y_1 Y_2] = -\text{Var}(X_i)$

Comment: @chp You didn't mention $\mathbb{E}X_i = 0$

Comment: @DenisKorzhenkov Right, but independent of the value of $\mathbb E[X_i]$, we have $\mathbb E[Y_1 Y_2] = -Var(X_i) \neq 0 = \mathbb E[Y_1]\mathbb E[Y_2]$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider the following example. Let $X_i=1$ and $X_i=2$ with probabilities $\frac14$ and $\frac34$, respectively; for all $i$.

Compute first

$$P(Y_{i}=0\ \cap \ Y_{i-1}=0)=P(X_{i+1}-X_i=0\ \cap \ X_i-X_{i-1}=0)$$
then compute

$$P(Y_{i}=0)=P(Y_{i-1}=0)=P(X_{i+1}-X_i=0).$$

So,

$$P(Y_{i}=0\ \cap \ Y_{i-1}=0)=P(X_{i+1}-X_i=0\ \cap \ X_i-X_{i-1}=0)=$$
$$=P(X_{i+1}-1=0\ \cap \ 1-X_{i-1}=0\mid X_i=1)\frac14+$$
$$+P(X_{i+1}-2=0\ \cap \ 2-X_{i-1}=0\mid X_i=2)\frac34=$$
$$=P(X_{i+1}-1=0)P(1-X_{i-1}=0)\frac14+P(X_{i+1}-2=0)P(2-X_{i-1}=0)\frac34=$$
$$=\frac1{64}+\frac{27}{64}=\frac{28}{64}$$

and

$$P(X_{i+1}-X_i=0)=\frac1{16}+\frac9{16}=\frac58$$

that is

$$P(Y_{i}=0)P(Y_{i-1}=0)=\frac{25}{64}.$$

Finally, since

$$P(Y_{i}=0\ \cap \ Y_{i-1}=0)\not =P(Y_{i}=0)P(Y_{i-1}=0)$$

we can tell that the $Y_i$s are not independent in general.

Comment: It might be quicker to spot $P(Y_{i}=1\ \cap \ Y_{i-i}=1)=0$ while $P(Y_{i}=1)P( Y_{i-i}=1)>0$